# How to select all faces contained within other faces?

Tags: faces, selection-tools

I want to select all faces that "share" space within another face. How do I select all, I would think there is a "select all by trait" or similar but can't find this specifically.

[image: Face contained within other face]

Comment: Do you want to select the neighbours, or like are they overlapping and you are not able to select the different faces or something like that? Please be a little bit more specific

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I essentially want a way to quickly find faces that share surface with another, face. I am able to select each of them manually, but I want a quick way to find all faces that are completely contained in the "bounding box" of another face. The square in the image is at the exact same "layer" as the larger one that it sits on. @Akshay2005

Comment: You could try the 3D-Print Toolbox addon. It has tools that can find intersecting faces, although if they are perfectly co-planer it has trouble finding those

Comment: You can Shift+G > Coplanar but this will give you all coplanar faces. Cant think of any other way. Just wait for an answer

Comment: I can think of an algorithm using geonodes or python but not an existing functionality.